# Why can't my jQuery script be used on two div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So my website has jQuery to show/hide div when I click on the prev and next logo.  It works perfectly fine on the first div but when I want to apply it on the second div with the same class it didn't work.

```js
function updateItems(delta) {

  var $items = $('.group').children();
  var $current = $items.filter('.current');
  $current = $current.length ? $current : $items.first();
  var index = $current.index() + delta;

  // Range check the new index
  index = (index < 0) ? 0 : ((index > $items.length) ? $items.length : index);
  $current.removeClass('current');
  $current = $items.eq(index).addClass('current');

  // Hide/show the next/prev
  //$(".prev").toggle(!$current.is($items.first()));    
  //$(".next").toggle(!$current.is($items.last()));   
}

$(".next").click(function() {
  updateItems(1);
});

$(".prev").click(function() {
  updateItems(-1);
});

// Cause initial selection
updateItems(0);
```

```css
.group div {
  display: none;
}

.group div.current {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #caa461;
}

.next,
.prev {
  float: right;
  font-size: 2vw;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-lg-8 text-justify reveal group">
  <div>
    <p>First Div</p>
  </div>

  <i class="fas fa-angle-right" id="next"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-angle-left" id="prev"></i>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-8 text-justify reveal group">
  <div>
    <p>Second Div</p>
  </div>

  <i class="fas fa-angle-right next"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-angle-left prev"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

The arrows do not know who they belong to

You did not have class next/prev on the second set of arrows

```js
function updateItems(tgtDiv, delta) {

  var $items = $(tgtDiv).children();
  var $current = $items.filter('.current');
  $current = $current.length ? $current : $items.first();
  var index = $current.index() + delta;

  // Range check the new index
  index = (index < 0) ? 0 : ((index > $items.length) ? $items.length : index);
  $current.removeClass('current');
  $current = $items.eq(index).addClass('current');

}

$(".next").click(function(e) {
  updateItems(e.target.closest("div"), 1);
});

$(".prev").click(function(e) {
  updateItems(e.target.closest("div"), -1);
});

// Cause initial selection
$(".group").each(function() {
  updateItems(this, 0)
})
```

```css
.group div {
  display: none;
}

.group div.current {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #caa461;
}

.next,
.prev {
  float: right;
  font-size: 2vw;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-lg-8 text-justify reveal group">
  <div>
    <p>First Div</p>
  </div>

  <i class="fas fa-angle-right next"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-angle-left prev"></i>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="col-lg-8 text-justify reveal group">
  <div>
    <p>Second Div</p>
  </div>

  <i class="fas fa-angle-right next"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-angle-left prev"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your response, the code did work, but when first i load the website div 2 was not shown. I have to click the next and move it back to show the div. Can you help me fix it ?

and one more i keep getting blank div at the and, i guess its because the next and prev <i> tag are detected as a div. Can you help me to get rid of that too ? Thanks Before

Comment: `$(".group").each(function() {  updateItems(this,0) });`

Comment: Thanks you so much, how about the blank div at the end, i its because the next and prev <i> tag are detected as a div. Can you help me to get rid of that too ? Thanks Before

Comment: Why would they be seen as a div?

Comment: I changed the ID to class next/prev on the arrows